# Issues with youtube video on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, iframe, video

I have an embed tag containing youtube video.

However this does not play on mobile browsers as it says flash required.

I am using HTML and not HTML 5 since my app should support IE 8 too.

I browsed through some awesome JQuery solutions but got only HTML5 based Jquery solutions

Can someone suggest me good solution to have my youtube video play in IE8+ , Chrome , FF+ and mobile browsers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This embed code youtube provides by default will work for HTML5 browsers (mobile phones) as well as old browsers that need flash:
[http://jsfiddle.net/austinpray/G5GhH/1](http://jsfiddle.net/austinpray/G5GhH/1/)

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

As best I can tell by looking at the iframe's code, this code sniffs the capabilities of what your browser can play and displays what works best. If you are on browser that has flash capabilities it uses flash and if flash isn't available it defaults to HTML 5. I tested this and it works on iPhones and Android phones. Here is the [Youtube support document](https://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171780).

Comment: I was just about to post this. I'm using this exact code in PhoneGap and for a web app. It's working great for me.

Comment: @AustinPray I tried the same thing in my phone but . WHile testing on Moto G it throws error  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757846/youtube-player-stops-after-few-seconds-on-mobile.