# YouTube player stops after few seconds on mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, youtube, google-chrome-devtools

I have a YouTube video embedded in my mobile webpage. On desktop, it plays properly. However, on mobile phone (emulated on Android), it stops after some time throwing an error.

When I debugged in console, following errors are generated:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://r13---sn-nx57yn7s.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?source=youtube&ipbit…s_redirect=yes&mm=30&ms=nxu&mt=1410325650&mv=u&range=0-65535&keepalive=yes`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://www.youtube.com`' is therefore not allowed access.

The **HTML** I am using for the video is like this

```
<iframe id="video1" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PLOUfmig96M?&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;hl=es_ES&amp;rel=0&amp;color1=0x2b405b&amp;color2=0x6b8ab6
&amp;fs=1&amp;border=1&amp;autoplay=1"></iframe>
```

**Error Image**

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: I don't understand. You state that it works on your desktop, but not on mobile. But you posted the error messages of the chrome console (pc). Am I missing something?

Comment: @alkis He's using [Chrome devtools - Emulator](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode).

Comment: @Omar Haven't seen this one before. I've learnt something new today. Thank you.

Comment: @Omar funny thing is that if I just play some video on youtube using the Dev tool it shows the same error . This is happening in the browser So i found out that the problem is not in the code . I guess its the dev tools I guess